# Import large sql file in WAMP 2.4 version

Tags: php, wamp

Recently I installed WAMP SERVER 2.4 version, I couldn't upload any sql file in phpmyadmin, I made few changes in the wamp root directory and here are:

```
(1) Increase " upload maximum file size " and “ maximum speed " while uploading files :
    C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

    post_max_size = 750M
    upload_max_filesize = 750M
    max_execution_time = 5000
    max_input_time = 5000
    memory_limit = 1000M

(2) And in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\my.ini
    max_allowed_packet = 200M

(3) Phpmyadmin stop Execution Time :
    C:\wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/libraries/config.default.php

    $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Finally, it didn't worked out. Could anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large/

Comment: you can use the php utility mysql dumper. http://www.mysqldumper.net/